# Python import modules, folder structures

Tags: python, path, relative-path, python-module

I have been looking for a way to solve this.

I have a python project, and this is the folder structure I want:

```
/project/main.py
/project/src/models.py
/project/test/tests.py
```

I want to be able to run the tests by executing the **tests.py** in terminal. tests.py imports modules in /project/src/ for testing. First I solved this by adding
 `sys.path.insert(0, '..')` in tests.py. But then the paths used in **models.py** for opening text files had to be relative to the **tests.py**, etc. Which means the program wouldn't run when excecuted from **main.py**, cause of the paths.

I also tried with **dots** when importing modules into tests.py, like `from ..src.models import *`, but that gave error message saying "Attempted relative import in non-package".

What should I  put in the top of tests.py to be able to import the modules from models.py?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 4):

The structure you're using is not one I would recommend, but I'm a comparaitive newb to how Python projects are usually structured. I believe this will do what you're after:

1) Place an `__init__.py` file inside `/project`, `/project/src`, and `/project/test` to make sure they're treated as packages.

2) Place `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the top of each Python file.

3) Then use relative imports:

`test.py`:

```
from ..src import models
```

`main.py`:

```
from .src import models
```

4) You'll need to start your application differently. Ensure your current directory is the parent of `/project` (which appears to be the file system root) and run your project this way:

```
python -m project.main
```

For my own project, I would definitely put `main.py` inside `src` if it's the start point of your application. I might put `tests.py` in `src`, too, but if not, I would add `/project/src` to the test runner's Python path on the command line instead of in code.

I would still use `absolute_import` regardless. In my experience, it's a very clean solution to module organization, and it's also how things work by default in Python 3.

Comment: I still get this: ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package. I got __init__.py everywhere now.

Comment: @user1121487 Yeah. Just realized that. Sorry. My edit should fix it, if you didn't figure it out already.

Comment: @user1121487 Updated. You have to run Python differently. I think this explains why I would arrange my files differently.

Comment: Still can't get it to work. ImportError: No module named models.

Comment: @user1121487 I can't reproduce that. How are you getting it?

Answer (score 0):

first put your main.py in the src directory..

in your tests you can do , sys.path.append('the src directory')

if you like to force the execution to be in specific directory regardless from where you are executing the app i suggest you adding

```
import os
os.chdir('relative path to the src dir')
```

thisway your program will run in the directory you specified so it will respect the relative paths you have in your code